# What do the subscripts mean in $N_{t,n,\sigma,L}$?

Tags: neural-networks, math, definitions, notation

A neural network can apparently be denoted as $N_{t,n,\sigma,L}$. What do these subscripts  $t, n, \sigma$ and $L$ mean? Could you link me to a paper, article or webpage with an explanation for this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Here](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1410.1141.pdf) is a paper with the mathematical definition of each term:

> Let N<sub>t,n,σ,L</sub> be all target functions that can be implemented using a
>   neural network of depth t, size n, activation function σ, and when we
>   restrict the input weights of each neuron to be |w|<sub>1</sub> + |b| ≤ L.

Comment: Does "size $n$" mean that the network has $n$ input nodes?

Comment: Check the introduction: "The depth of the network is the number of layers and the size of the network is the total number of neurons."